Unity Editor just freezes when completing script
IDK, but when i am trying to start my script, unity editor just freezes (but responding!), but theres no warnings, errors, or anything.
Heres a part of code, that i changed:
public partial class UseItem()
{
    ...
    else if (this.item[this.itemSelected] == 5)
    {
        Ray ray3 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3((float)(Screen.width / 2), (float)(Screen.height / 2), 0f));
        RaycastHit raycastHit3;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray3, out raycastHit3))
        {
            if (raycastHit3.collider.name == "BSODAMachine" & Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, raycastHit3.transform.position) <= 10f)
            {
                ResetItem();
                raycastHit3.collider.gameObject.name = "EmptyMachine";
                raycastHit3.collider.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = OutOfBsoda;
                raycastHit3.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
                while (raycastHit3.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
                {

                }
                CollectItem(4);
            }
            ...
}

Any ideas how to fix it?
I am tried to change other else ifs, but, nothing

Do you have any chance to leave the while loop?

Note that while your script is running then nothing else happens. I.e., the game status is not updated (time stands still). Once your script ends, then the game loop takes over and makes things happen.

while (raycastHit3.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying) is an infiniate loop, it doesnt even have some form of break/yield in a couroutine, its just gonna infinitely go up its butt.. here here is your issue

Oh, i just new in c#, tysm, @BugFinder
